# How webpages like Statigram doesn't exceed Instagram API rate limits

Tags: api, limit, instagram

Well, pretty much what it says on the tin.

I'm really curious about how pages like Statigram do their search functionality without users authentication and not exceeding the limits?

If I'm correct, Instagram API allows 5000 calls per hour, so I believe it's very likely that they indeed have more traffic than 5000 requests per hour.

Maybe It's a dumb question and Statigram has a special deal with Instagram to use their API or maybe they don't use the API and they use some other method?

Comment: Either a special deal, credential/IP address rotating, heavy caching or screenscraping.

Comment: thanks @RunscopeAPITools, I really appreciate the answer, if you don't mind I'll wait for some others to reply to see other opinions, please make your comment an answer so I can later mark it as resolved.

Comment: @RunscopeAPITools BTW, those method wouldn't be violating the social network's terms of use (apart from a special deal of course)?

Comment: They do not have any special arrangements with Instagram, if you read the API docs you will see that they encourage app developers to authorize users (as Statigr.am does) which the app an access_token specific to that user, hence, the limit is never hit :)

Comment: @jonathanwiesel i have the same question in mind as well

Comment: @TomHall how do websites do it? I see websites don't ask users to authorize using their site

Comment: @jsmoove88 If a website doesn't ask a user to login & authorise using Instagram then they will simply have to use their assigned client id/secret to make calls to the Instagram API, that's 5000 requests per hour. If however a website does log users in using Instagram, then as part of the process, the website will be given an access_token specific to that user, which can be used to make calls to the Instagram API - so thats 5000 requests per hour, per user = you (probably) won't get rate limited.

Comment: Hi @jonathanwiesel I think you've selected the wrong answer. Darryl Clarke's answer is definitely correct. The Runscope answer is possible but unlikely, and it's not a good general purpose answer for the majority of people who come here looking to learn about the Instagram API -- and not Statigram (now Iconosquare) in particular.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely they're using one of the following methods:

- An arrangement with Instagram
- Credential rotation
- IP rotation
- Heavy caching (especially across credentials or IPs)
- Screenscraping

In cases like this, if you don't have a special arrangement, you're almost certainly violating the terms of service. If you think your service is useful enough that Instagram would be willing to whitelist you to make more requests, get in touch with them.

Comment: its about limiting requests from the same access_token not IP.

Comment: Agree - nothing to do with IP rotation

Answer (score 34):

The only special request you have to send to Instagram is the request to post comments.

The API limit is 5000 requests per hour per `access_token` or `client_id`. Every user has their own `access_token`, so as long as the requests from the third party application uses each individual access token, they will be hard pressed to exceed 5000 per user per hour.

That works out to 83 requests per minute and any user interacting with your application is highly unlikely to hit that.

From the docs:

> You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id overall. Practically, this means you should (when possible) authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a given user.

If you are not using user authentication, you will likely hit the limit with just your `client_id`.

Comment: this should have been the selected answer.

Comment: I also second best answer. It actually answers the question and not complete assumption.

Answer (score -2):

They must have some sort of arrangement with Instagram as @RunscopeAPITools mentions. You are able to post comments to Instagram from Statigram, which requires special permission.