# Instagram blocks website's IP?

Tags: php, server, instagram, ddos

I recently created a website with PHP to Check Out Anyone's Instagram Profile Picture at Full Size!. Yesterday my service stopped to work and it seems as if Instagram is blocking my web servers IP-address.
I then started to try to fix the issue but unfortunately, I could not reproduce the error locally. I put my code up on another server and tried to check if the error is because I made a mistake. But as the service works on my another web server , I expect Instagram to block my original web servers IP-address.

How can I fix this or reproduce the error? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly look into this https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/issues/648 (most APIs have limits for users to do, like 10 req. per minute or on a per-hourly basis, talk to their tech team to see if your server can get a whitelist or more per/hour/minute, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

If your code works with different IP addresses then you've almost certainly been blocked by Instagram.

This answer highlights some of the steps you can take.

[How webpages like Statigram doesn't exceed Instagram API rate limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156439/how-webpages-like-statigram-doesnt-exceed-instagram-api-rate-limits)

Such as the following.

1. An arrangement with Instagram
2. Credential rotation
3. IP rotation
4. Heavy caching (especially across credentials or IPs)

In my experience (Not with Instagram) Credential Rotation is the easiest/cheapest option to implement.