# php via windows cmd - multiple instances

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I am quite new in this realm so please be patient :)

I have a rather complex PHP script that I run from windows prompt.

This goes just fine but now I want to run a few instances of this script on the same machine and installation of PHP.

I am using a new Windows prompt each time and a varation of the original script with in part differing parameters. It seems to work..

Is it possible there are interferences or is it not - because it is different processes (PIDs)?

Thanks for your help!
H.

Comment: They are seperate processes, with encapsulated memory areas for their variables, nothing will interfere there. If you access external things like files/DB/caches, they are obviously "shared".

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for that! In my project I have to run a handful of instances of this: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API - session/cookie data is stored in a separate folder for each user - that´s obviously why it does work - I don´t have SQL running or so - apart from that I don´t see any external data dump...

Comment: Every instance of your program is calling the Instagram API from the same IP (the public IP of your machines network interface / router). I guess there is some rate-limiting on Instagrams API, so the more instances you run the more likely the chance you run into these, as Instagram only has 1 counter for your IP.

Comment: Good point, but  if I had multiple "real" users in the same Wifi- wouldn´t it also be the same IP for Instagram? Like in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156439/how-webpages-like-statigram-doesnt-exceed-instagram-api-rate-limits it seems the limit counts per acces_token / client_id. I am just curious if anything else might bring this down..